# How to select a span after a checkbox with $$this with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I click on the checkbox I want to change the color on the "Publicera" text in the span.

No matter what I try I can´t get it to work. And I don´t understand why this isn´t working?

```
$$(this).closest("div").find(".pub1").css('color','red');
```

```html
<div class="item-subtitle">                   
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <i class="icon-checkbox"></i>
  </label>&nbsp;
  <span class="pub1" style="color:#0CF;">Publicera</span> 
</div>
```

So any input really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why $$(this) ???

Comment: Also, *what* is `this`?

Comment: I guess 'this' isn't even displayed in the html because he/she works with closest("div").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".pub1").attr("style", "").css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-subtitle">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <i class="icon-checkbox"></i>
  <span class="pub1" style="color:#0CF;">Publicera</span>
    </label>&nbsp;
</div>
```

or like this

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".pub1").toggleClass("cyan red")
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.cyan {
  color: #0CF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-subtitle">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <i class="icon-checkbox"></i>
  <span class="pub1 cyan">Publicera</span>
    </label>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be defined event change for the Checkbox

```js
   $("#checkBox").change(function () {
        $("div > .pub1").css('color','red');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-subtitle">

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
        <i class="icon-checkbox"></i>
    </label>&nbsp;
    <span class="pub1" style="color:#0CF;">Publicera</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.